# Comparing the last value of two multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a very simple form of a Roulette in JavaScript, object oriented. I set up a board of 8 (red 1, white 2, red 3, white 4 ... white 8) and I pick a random position where the ball would fall with Math.random.

```
this.randomPick = function() { 
      var randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - 1) + 1); 
      var selectedPos = this.board[randomPos]; 
      console.log(selectedPos); 
};
```

I also ask the user to fill in a colour and a number (red or white, 1 - 8).

But then I am stuck, how can I compare if the user's input is equal to the place where the ball fell?

```
this.board = [["rood", 1], ["wit", 2], ["rood", 3], ["wit", 4], ["rood", 5], ["wit", 6], ["rood", 7], ["wit", 8]];

this.userInput = function(){
    var inzet = E("inzet").value;
    var kleur = E("kleur").value;
    var nummer = E("nummer").value;

    this.userIn.push(kleur, nummer);
};
```

Comment: How are you storing user number, and how are you storing the number the ball lands on? You just need to compare them two: `if(ballNumber == userNumber)`

Comment: I am afraid it is harder than that, as I need to compare userNumber to ballNumber and userColour to ballColour. And I have the multidimensional array of this.board and I store the user's values in this.userIn.

Comment: Do you have the array coordinates of where the ball fell?

Comment: You should provide more code, we cannot see how you are determining which number the ball falls on.

Comment: this.randomPick = function() {
        var randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - 1) + 1);
        var selectedPos = this.board[randomPos];

        console.log(selectedPos);
    };

Answer (score 1):

Two step solution. 
1.Push the the user input color and value into a new array ar.
2.compare that that array with all elements of your two dim array.

```
ar = new Array();
ar.push(user_chosen_color);
ar.push(user_chosen_value);

for(i=0;i<two_dim_array.length;i++)
{
    if(ar==two_dim_array[i])
    {
        // Do what you want to do
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
ar = new Array();
ar.push(user_chosen_color);
ar.push(user_chosen_value);


function caompare(ar , two_dim_array)
{        
    var res = "Nothing";
    for(i=0;i<two_dim_array.length;i++)
    {
         if(ar[0]==two_dim_array[i][0])
         {
             res = "Color";
             if(ar[1]==two_dim_array[i][1])                 
                 res = "Both";                 
         }
         else
         {
              if(ar[1]==two_dim_array[i][1])                 
                 res = "Value";
         }
    }
    return res;
}
var res = compare(ar, two_dim_array);
// Now you have result in res
```

Comment: Is it also possible to give two kinds of results? The user fictively pays to play, if only the colour is correct, he wins 0.2 times of what he paid. If the number is correct, he gains 5.0 times of what he paid.

Comment: Four cases, I believe, yes. Colour correct, value correct, both correct, both false.

Comment: Sorry had an error (i did used only ar[0] and not ar[1]). Try now. And if it does not give result, then edit your question to show me how you are trying it. I will make it working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
8 reds + 8 blacks = 16 total possibly choices. 

//red
array[1] = 1;
...
array[8] = 8;
//black
array[9] = 1;
array[10] = 2;
....
array[16] = 8;

var user_number = 1; //0 even 1 odd
var user_color = 0; //0 black 1 red
var tempa = 0;

for (var loopa = 1; loopa <= 8; loopa++){
  if( user_color == 0){ tempa = loopa + 8; } else { tempa = loopa;} //black or red
     if ( user_number == array[tempa]){ //checks number
     //do something
     }
  }
}
```

================
for each type of winning for rolute would be another for/if  statments.

get "google chrome" browser
load up your webpage...
top right corner click on the 3 bars icon
goto down to TOOLS
then click JAVASCRIPT CONSLE

you can type in say...
array
and then click arrows to see listings of array variables or see info about say...
user_number
to see what it is currently holding.

might help visualize things